# Correct command to get domain whois info

Tags: whois

If I use `# whois google.ru` ssh command then I get proper whois information.
But if I try to use the same for the following domain I fail:

```
htaccess.net.ru
```

The response I get is `No entries found for the selected source(s).`

This domain is in someway similar to .co.uk.
That is you cannot register example.uk but you can register example.co.uk

Comment: For what it is worth, yesterday the .UK registry launched direct .UK registrations. So it is actually now possible to register `yourname.uk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently encountered this issue myself at GWhois.org (example: http://gwhois.org/htaccess.net.ru)

The issue is that the .RU registry has 2 whois servers:

- whois.tcinet.ru
- whois.nic.ru

The first one is the one [listed at IANA](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/ru.html), so it is assummed to be the authoritative one.

Unfortunately, this server does not support lookups for the .RU registry's `.net.ru` and other second level domain names.

In the command prompt, you will need to to set the whois server manually like so:

```
whois -h whois.nic.ru htaccess.net.ru
```

Comment: It is because `RU` and `NET.RU` are different domain name registries and TLDs, managed by different organizations. So each one has its own whois server. IANA website only takes care of the ccTLD. `net.ru` `org.ru` `pp.ru` are managed by MSK-IX based on the PSL and you can find a lot of further details here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/whois-server-list/whois-server-list/master/whois-server-list.xml